# How to compute $P(A_k)$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Toss a coin with $P(\text{Heads}) = p$ repeatedly. Let $A_k$ be the
>   event that $k$ or more consecutive heads occur among the tosses
>   numbered $2^k, 2^k+1, \dots, 2^{k+1}-1$. Compute $P(A_k)$

I don't know why the following is wrong:

$$P(A_k) = \sum_{i=k}^{2^k} p^i (1-p)^{2^k-i} (2^k-i+1)$$

(This is not hard to bring into closed form, although is a little long)

But I am pretty sure it's wrong.. Here is my reasoning:

If we want exactly $i$ consecutive heads, then we can position them in exactly $2^k - i + 1$ ways (i.e. $HHHTT, THHHT, TTHHH$ and so on). We get $p^i(1-p)^{2^k-i} (2^k-i+1)$. 
Then sum for all $i\ge k$ and of course $i \le 2^k$

What's wrong with that?

**EDIT**

Actually, I see what is wrong. Let's say that I look for $2$ consecutive heads, I did not take into consideration something like $HHTHT$

How to compute $P(A_k)$ then?